# Database Query to get sum of count from different tables in a single query

Tags: java, mysql, database, database-design

I am writing a query in Mysql database, in which 
Query 1 returns count(*) say result is 10
and 
Query 2 returns Count(*) say result is 30

But I want to get the result as 40, which is sum of both

what are my options to get a single query giving me the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `UNION ALL` to union also the same valued counts like 30+30.

```
select SUM(n) as total
from (
  (select count(*) as n from table1)
  UNION ALL
  (select count(*) as n from table2)
) t;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(num) as total
from (
  (select count(*) as num from table1)
  UNION ALL
  (select count(*) as num from table2)
) a;
```

Comment: If both subqueries return 30, it won't return 60, instead will return 30.

Comment: indeed.  thanks for that.  I'll make the correction... though you've already posted the answer yourself I see.

Comment: @Pentium, As mentioned above comments, what is the fix for If both subqueries return 30, it won't return 60, instead will return 30